# Parallel extract of data from MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

I have an application where I need to extract a large amount of data from a table in a MemSQL database.   I would like to be able to run extractors that read the data from each leaf node in parallel.  Is there a way to do this in MemSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect directly to the leaf nodes and read from the partition databases (the databases like db_0, see show partitions). This isn't usually recommended, but this should generally be fine as long as you're only reading from the leaves directly, and there's no DDL, clustering operations, etc happening at the same time.

Comment: Keep in mind your circumventing the normal locking MemSQL does on the aggregator if you query leaf nodes directly (so failover, adding new nodes, rebalance partitions, etc. can move partition databases well your querying them).